# jquery autocomplete not working correctly with django

Tags: jquery, python, django, autocomplete

I want to implement autocomplete functionality on my web page using django. I went ahead with jquery autocomplete which has sufficient documentation on how to achieve it. I have made changes accordingly to my django views and urls as well. Still I am not able to view any entries in autocomplete.

Below are code fragments which would give a clear idea of how i implemented it

**mypage.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

...
...

<script>
$(function() {
var entries= [
  "emp1",
  "emp2",
  "emp3",
  "emp4",
  "emp5"
];
$("#vote").autocomplete({
  source: "api/get_employees/",
});
});
</script>

...
...
...

<div class="ui-widget">
<input id="vote" type="text" name="vote"/>
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</div>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^api/get_employees/', views.get_employees, name='get_employees')
```

views.py

```
def get_employees(request):
    data = ['MyName']
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data),'application/json')
```

I have tried passing [{id:'MyName'}] to data as well. But still I dont get it during autocomplete.
I am sure nothing is wrong with the jquery part because if i pass entries variable to source, everything works fine. Only when i change it to get data from the django view, it runs into issues.
Any pointers in this regard would be helpful. I have tried other posts in stackoverflow but to no avail.

Comment: check your ajax call with inspect element(chrome) or firebug(firefox) and check if there are any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks to all the answers. They helped me form the correct json to pass back. But then i found out that I missed a line "import json". Everything was working fine even without this line which i am clueless about. Again any pointers appreciated.

After doing the import and passing correct json back, I am able to see the list of entries with autocomplete.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON should look like this:

```
[
    {
    "id":"Ficedula hypoleuca",
    "label":"Eurasian Pied Flycatcher",
    "value":"Eurasian Pied Flycatcher"
    },
    {
    "id":"Muscicapa striata",
    "label":"Spotted Flycatcher",
    "value":"Spotted Flycatcher"
    }
]
```

When you look at the example at http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote you can see that the autocomplete is 'asking' `http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/search.php`

You should also use `/api/get_employees/` instead of `api/get_employees/`

Maybe this is also importend(for your django-part):
jquery uses the parameter term to for the searchword.
For example http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/search.php?**term=ca** is searching for 'ca'

Answer (score 1):

The Autocomplete documentation is not very clear. To make it work, you will need to ensure that `api/get_employees?term=...` will return a JSON array structured like so:

```
[ {"value":"3","label":"Matching employee A"},
  {"value":"5","label":"Matching employee B"},
  etc.
]
```